# How to insert 100 records in mysql procedure and loop in MySQL procedure not in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a record of 100 or 200 questions when user submit the test all 100 or 200 questions from caches need to save to MySQL. Right now I have to loop in PHP and every time a single query has executed,  any idea how I send an array in MySQL procedure and the loop of 100 or 200 should be done in MySQL procedure. I can convert the array to JSON as JSON is supported in MySQL.

array which needs to be insert looks like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 19287
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 101
        [4] => 224
        [5] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 19285
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 101
        [4] => 2
        [5] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 19289
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 72
        [4] => 23
        [5] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 19290
        [1] => 
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 106
        [4] => 3
        [5] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 19291
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 230
        [4] => 76
        [5] => 0
    )
)
```

Comment: You could just built a multi-row insert, as that is supported by MySQL. You don't need a stored procedure.

Comment: My entire project is in stored procedures so I have to this in MySQL procedures only.

Comment: Well, OK. Did you do a search for this? If you try something like "MySQL stored procedure loop" in a search engine, you may find a pre-existing answer without needing to ask a fresh question.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a multi-row `INSERT` in your PHP code. Assuming your data is in `$arr`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (...column list...) VALUES ";
$vsets = array();
foreach ($arr as $values) {
    $vsets[] = str_replace(array(',,', ',,'), ',NULL,', "(" . implode(',', $values) . ")");
}
$sql .= implode(',', $vsets);
echo $sql;
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (...column list...) 
    VALUES (19287,1,1,101,224,0),(19285,0,1,101,2,0),
           (19289,1,1,72,23,0),(19290,NULL,1,106,3,0),
           (19291,0,1,230,76,0)
```

Make sure you filter, validate or cast your data, to prevent any non-integers (or any SQL) from being injected into your queries.

Comment: Some care would need to be taken to ensure all values are int, e.g. casting.

Comment: @halfer you're absolutely right but without knowing OPs structure it's hard to write code to do the appropriate conversions. I'm just working from the data in the question.

Comment: I need to do in MySQL procedure as my entire project is in MySQL procedures any help that will be helpfull

Comment: @Deepeshsingh you say in the question that you are using PHP. So why not do the work there?

Comment: I am so sorry I was not able to explain it properly. I am working on Laravel and not using eloquent. I am using MySQL procedures to write every query

Comment: If you could give an example of how you are currently writing queries I can probably modify the answer to suit.